# $(S-T)^{-1}$ exists if $T$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $T,S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ two linear transformations on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose that $T\circ S = S \circ T$ and $S^{-1}$ exists. Then

$(S-T)^{-1}$ exists if $T$ is nilpotent.

I'm only get that $(I-T)$ is invertible, but with $S$ in the place of $I$ didnt work. I don't know how the two hypothesis would work on this... If someone have a light, I appreciate that!

Comment: This is certainly not an if and only if. Let $S=2I,T=I$.

Comment: Sorry, the correct statement is $(S-T)^{-1}$ exists if $T$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Hint: $S-T=S(I-S^{-1}T)$

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: It works, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $T^n=0$, and $T^{n-1}\neq0$. Since $S$ and $T$ commute, so do $S^{-1}$ and $T$ and $(S^{-1}T)^k=(S^{-1})^kT^k=(S^{k})^{-1}T^k=T^k(S^{-1})^k$. A simple calculation shows that
$$\big(I+(S^{-1}T)+\ldots+(S^{-1}T)^{n-1}\big)(I-S^{-1}T)= I-(S^{-1}T)^n=I$$
and
$$\big(I-(S^{-1}T)\big)\big(I+(S^{-1}T)+\ldots+(S^{-1}T)^{n-1}\big)= I-(S^{-1}T)^n=I$$
Hence $(I-S^{-1}T)$ is invertible. Consequently, $S(I-S^{-1}T)=(S-T)$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose T is invertible and $T^n=0$
Then

A:    $S^n = S^n - T^n = (S-T)(S^{n-1}+S^{n-2}T+.. +ST^{n-2}+T^{n-1})$

$S$ inverttible ==> $S^n$ is invertible.   Multiply both sides of (A) by the inverse to $S^n$ and you have:

$$1 = (S-T) ( (S^{n-1}+S^{n-2}T+.. +ST^{n-2}+T^{n-1}) )S^{-n})$$

So T nilpotent and S invertible ==> S-T invertible.

The if and only if statement is:
If T is nilpotent:  S-T is invertible <==> S is invertible.